Referencing another notebook in Synapse from different Folder
I am trying to reference notebook in another notebook using mssparkutils.notebook.run and it would initially work, however when I introduced more folders and subfolders it stopped
What I've done in the past was
env = 'test'

mssparkutils.notebook.run(path="Load Data from SAP", arguments={"environment": f"{env}" }) 

The error is 404, claims this notebook is not existing. It does, however in folder MasterData and subfolder SKU
I tried different approaches like
env = 'test'

mssparkutils.notebook.run(path="/MasterData/SKU/Load Data from SAP", arguments={"environment": f"{env}" }) 

or
env = 'test'

mssparkutils.notebook.run(path="Notebooks/MasterData/SKU/Load Data from SAP", arguments={"environment": f"{env}" })

Nothing seem to work. How to reference that properly? My notebooks are published
**
Tagging also databricks because its similar there but dbutils not msspark **

Are you trying run notebook which is in databricks workspace from another notebook?

If the Notebooks level is like
Notebook1
folder1
    mynotebook
    subfolder1
        mynotebook2

then, you need to give the path like below from Notebook 1 to achieve your requirement.
env = 'test'

mssparkutils.notebook.run(path="/folder1/subfolder1/mynotebook2", arguments={"environment": f"{env}" })


To overcome the error, make sure you publish all the notebooks and also try troubleshooting steps like checking connection and clearing the browser cache.
